# Is a volume defined in manifold with spacetime-signature?

Tags: manifolds, volume, curvature

A **volume** in $R^n$ is easily calculated by multiplying the lengths of the $n$ dimensions.

I'm wondering how the different sign of time acts on the **volume** in a manifold with spacetime signature (1,3).
Is a **volume** *defined at all* in such a manifold?

Comment: The *line* element $ds^2$ is given by the metric, for example the Schwarzschild-metric $ds^2=c^2\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)dt^2-\frac{1}{1-\frac{r_s}{r}} dr^2-r^2d\theta^2-r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$. However, I don't see how to calculate a *volume* element from that. Does time adds _negatively_ to the spatial volume? Or probably _inversly_?

Comment: Inversely would mean one had to calculate for example $dV_{(1,3) } = \frac{dx\cdot dy\cdot dz} {dt} $. Sorry if that's too stupid and speculative... That's why I only put it in a comment

Comment: Yes, it is. Did you read any semi Riemannian geometry textbooks?

Comment: I'm afraid no. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: @MoisheKohan And how is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the volume form $\omega$ is essentially the same as in the Riemannian case: If $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ is an oriented basis in $T_pM$, then
$$
\omega(e_1,...,e_n)= \sqrt{|\det(g)|},
$$
where $g=(g_{ij})$ is the semi-Riemannian metric on $T_pM$ in terms of the above basis. Or, if you prefer local (oriented) coordinates, then
$$
\omega= \sqrt{|\det(g(x))|}dx^1 ... dx^n.
$$
My favorite reference is

*O’Neill, Barrett*, Semi-Riemannian geometry. With applications to relativity, Pure and Applied Mathematics, 103. New York-London etc.: Academic Press. xiii, 468 p.  (1983). [ZBL0531.53051](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0531.53051).

Comment: That means that the opposite sign of time has _no_ influence on the volume???

Comment: @BarrierRemoval Right, except for the absolute value.